# Is Google Cloud Endpoints intended for creating RESTful APIs?

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been searching lately for tools that can be used for developing a RESTful API in App Engine. I have read a lot about RESTlet and RESTEasy.

I just stumbled upon **Google Cloud Endpoints** and I can't seem to tell whether it works the same RESTlet and RESTEasy.

Is **Google Cloud Endpoints** intended for creating RESTful APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Endpoints can be used to create REST APIs, however, that is not the primary intent. The intent is to allow usage of the APIs across multiple platforms for which a communication library is included with Endpoints. Specifically, it allows Android, iOS and JavaScript apps to easily communicate with the same endpoint, probably by taking care of conversion from JSON to Java/Objective-C objects.

Comment: Whether an API is RESTful or not is orthogonal to the target platforms (re. your comment on primary intent). RESTful APIs are a fully-supported use-case of Endpoints, but you are not required to make your APIs RESTful.

Comment: @DanHolevoet what I meant was the primary focus of the product/team is to include more and more target platforms and support them better, as opposed to a better REST API toolkit. Sure they could do both but when there is a tradeoff the erring would be on the side of target platform support rather than better REST support. It is nice that RESTful APIs are supported though; it is almost a necessity for any kind of API layer now.